# Codeigniter database config

Tags: php, mysql, macos, codeigniter, xampp

Whenever I try to connect to my project, I leave the default settings of codeigniter to take over for the database connection.

But there are times when it suddenly rejects the connection which will then trigger me to change the connection host to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' whichever is applicable and then it works

Can someone help me understand this?

EDIT:
I'm on macOS Sierra, using XAMPP 7.0.5

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoload database libraries may solve your issue.

Go to

> application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Yadhu, Though, I want to know what may be causing this error?